# Flutter - re-run previous page code after execution returns to it

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement the proper navigation flow of a flutter app I'm building that involves a 3rd party authentication page (Azure AD B2C). Currently I have a page that serves simply as a "navigate to 3rd party auth login" page which is set as the `initialRoute` for my app. The first time through, it runs exactly the way I want it to, but I'm not able to figure out how to get that 'navigate to auth' page to re-run when navigated back to (after logout) so that the user ends up back at the 3rd party auth login page.

Basically what I'd like to do is, on logout - have the app navigate back to that page specified as the `initialRoute` page, and upon that page being navigated back to, have it re-launch the 3rd party auth login page just like it did the first time it executed.

I tried just `await`ing the call to `Navigator.push()` and then calling `setState((){})` afterwards, and that does re-display the page, but it just leaves that initial page sitting there, and doesn't end up triggering the execution the way it did the first time. initState() does not fire again, so neither does any of my code that's in there.

I've tried various methods off the Navigator object trying to reload the page or navigate to itself again, or just calling `goToLogin()` again after the `await Navigator.push()` call, nothing works.

Here's what I'm currently doing :

1. User launches the app, the initialRoute is `LoginRedirect`

```
class LoginRedirect extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginRedirectState createState() => _LoginRedirectState();
}

class _LoginRedirectState extends State<LoginRedirect> {
  @override
  void initState() {

    Utility.getConfig().then((value) {
      config = value;
      oauth = AadOAuth(config);
      goToLogin(context);
    });

    super.initState();

  }


  void goToLogin(BuildContext context) async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });

    try {
      await oauth.login(); // this launches the 3rd party auth screen which returns here after user signs in
      String accessToken = await oauth.getAccessToken();

      navigateToDashboard();

      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });

    } on Exception catch (error) {
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    }

  }

  void navigateToDashboard() {
    await navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Dashboard()));

    // right here is where I'd like to call goToLogin() again after I Navigator.popUntil() back to this 
    // page, but if I try that I get an error page about how 'The specified child already
    // has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first., java.lang
    // .IllegalStateException and something about the bottom overflowed by 1063 pixels
  }

}
```

2. After getting some config values and calling `oauth.login()` then I call a `navigateToDashboard()` method that pushes the Dashboard page on to the navigation stack.

Elsewhere in the code I have a logout button that ends up calling this code:

```
oauth.logout();
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/LoginRedirect'));
```

which returns execution to where I called `await Navigator.push()` previously. But I can't figure out what I need to do there to have that LoginRedirect page execute again. I can't call `goToLogin()` again or it errors/crashes. I can't call `initState()` again, calling `setState()` doesn't do anything. I'm kinda stumped here, I thought this would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

When logging out try: `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/LoginRedirect");` instead of `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/LoginRedirect'));`

Comment: Yeah I tried that too - it causes the exception I mentioned in my original post - "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. java.lang.IllegalStateException". It's like it isn't allowing me to navigate to that page for some reason.